# Azure SQL ServerValidation failed for "vulnerabilityAssessments_Default_storageContainerPath"

Tags: azure, templates, deployment, cloud

I created a SQL server on Azure Cloud using the user interface. I want to automate the creation of this resource within a resource group. I have two template scenarios: one created from the resource itself and the other created from the resource group to which the server belongs. I delete the SQL server and then create the resource as follows:

New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -Name SQlDeployExample -ResourceGroupName MyGroup -TemplateFile template.json -TemplateParameterFile parameters.json

When I use the template generated by the resource's user interface, everything works perfectly. However, when I use the template generated by the resource group's user interface, I encounter this error:

`Error: Code=InvalidTemplate; Message=Deployment template validation failed: 'The value for the | template parameter 'vulnerabilityAssessments_Default_storageContainerPath' at line '7' and column '66' is not | provided.`

In both cases, the resource group is empty before executing the installation command.

Is there something I should do to avoid this error?
Why should I give this value when created from the resource group but not from the resource?

I tried to set a value in the parameters file, but the deploy freeze...

Answer (score 0):

The Storage account is required if you deploy the Azure SQL DB with [Classic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/defender-for-cloud/sql-azure-vulnerability-assessment-enable#classic-configuration) configuration for vulnerability assessment.

However, [Express](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/defender-for-cloud/sql-azure-vulnerability-assessment-enable#express-configuration) configuration is the modern approach that doesn't require a storage account for storing the scan results as it is managed by Azure itself.

The template that required the storage account looks like working in classic mode. so you need to use the Express configuration

More info is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/defender-for-cloud/sql-azure-vulnerability-assessment-manage)

Comment: Thank you! I did not enable Defender. I tried removing the section for storage. Got a bit farther. Then the problem was that I did not provide the admin password, corrected manually also (by using AD login which was incorrect in the generated template). Then a bunch of errors about multiple sections (DbParameterization, DefragmentIndex, servers/databases/auditingSettings, etc. were not found...).